# Splitting string variable into many variables in r

Tags: r, split

I want to create 4 varaibles out of 1 one varaibe.

Variable    Var1    var2    var3    var4
Upholstery KCDF  Venetian Beige Leatherette N/C Upholstery  KCDF    Venetian Beige Leatherette  N/C
 Accessories Z06    Black Kidney Grilles 173.00  Accessories    Z06     Black Kidney Grilles    173

or splitting " Accessories Z06    Black Kidney Grilles 173.00" this into
 Accessories    Z06     Black Kidney Grilles    173

Comment: You mentioned creating 4 variables out of 1 variable.  It is not clear where the splitting should occur in the example "Accessories Z06 ......173.00".  If you split by `space`, then it should be 6 variables.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide your data in a form we can reproduce, I made a mock set:

```
> furn <- c("Upholstery KCDF", "Venetian Beige Leatherette N/C", "Upholstery KCDF", "Venetian Beige Leatherette N/C",  "Accessories Z06", "Black Kidney Grilles 173.00", "Accessories Z06", "Black Kidney Grilles 173")
```

Then, with the `stringi` package you can separate words at the spaces and `unlist` the result as a vector:

```
> require(string1)

> unlist(stri_split_regex(str = furn, pattern = " "))
 [1] "Upholstery"  "KCDF"        "Venetian"    "Beige"       "Leatherette" "N/C"         "Upholstery"  "KCDF"       
 [9] "Venetian"    "Beige"       "Leatherette" "N/C"         "Accessories" "Z06"         "Black"       "Kidney"     
[17] "Grilles"     "173.00"      "Accessories" "Z06"         "Black"       "Kidney"      "Grilles"     "173"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `strsplit`

```
split.var <- strsplit(my.var, " ")
```

However, this will split at all spaces, so you may have to recode your original data to use a different separator.

Answer (score 0):

This example will help you.

```
library(base)
a<-"welcome to stack overflow"
b<-strsplit(a," ")
b<-unlist(b)
b1<-as.matrix(a)
a1<-b[1]
a2<-b[2]
a3<-b[3]
a4<-b[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly: the single string should be formatted in a table as:

```
       Variable      Var1      var2        var3   var4 
Upholstery KCDF  Venetian     Beige Leatherette    N/C 
Upholstery KCDF  Venetian     Beige Leatherette    N/C  
Accessories Z06     Black    Kidney Grilles     173.00  
Accessories Z06     Black    Kidney Grilles        173
```

Now, if the data is was in a deliminated file the function `read.table` should do what you need.

However, if the data is a single string such as:

```
input <- "Variable Var1 var2 var3 var4 Upholstery KCDF  Venetian Beige Leatherette N/C Upholstery KCDF Venetian Beige Leatherette N/C  Accessories Z06    Black Kidney Grilles 173.00  Accessories Z06  Black Kidney Grilles 173"
```

Then we have a different problem and a different solution will be needed.